# change audio route when the audio is playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I have an audio file that plays using avaudioplayer, I want to able to play the sound on the device receiver or speaker when the audio is playing when the user presses a button. How can I do that ? Currently it just plays on whatever was selected before the audio started playing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
OSStatus result = AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride );
Assert(result == kAudioSessionNoError);
```

Comment: I don't think apple will approve this

Comment: Please note that this method is now deprecated (since iOS 6)

Answer (score 2):

iOS 6+ version

```
NSError* error;

AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add MPVolume control ([link to documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) to your user interface and set showsVolumeSlider = NO and  showsRouteButton = YES.

User will have a route button to route the audio to a device of their choice.